# Click feature doesn't work dash-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, popup, dashboard, plotly, dash

I've created one dashboard with spatial data and plot it with dash-leaflet package.

The main screen above:

[image]

The goal is create a popup filled by picture map like it:

[image]

I put the monitoramento-dissolve data, that I read from postgis table, in DataStore component. before, there is a filter of date, and then it renders spatial data into map (canvas).
After that I tried to create click feature to pick id of polygon and show it in popup. However it doesn't work. Nothing I tried work.

Here is the configuration of callback (that I described above):
[image]

What I want to know is why my GeoJSON components doesn't answer clik_feature function in callback?

The code of map components:

```
import base64
import json

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Input, Output, callback


# Using base64 encoding and decoding
def b64_image(image_filename):
    with open(image_filename, 'rb') as f:
        image = f.read()
    return 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64.b64encode(image).decode('utf-8')

map_ = dbc.Row([
    dl.Map([dl.TileLayer(), dl.GeoJSON(id="geojson-mapa", children=[dl.Popup(id="popup", maxWidth = 500, minWidth=350)])],
    preferCanvas=True, maxBounds=[[-8.5272, -46.6294], [-18.3484, -37.3338]],
    id="leaflet-map", style={"height": "92vh"} #92vh
    )])

# Callback mapa
@callback(
    Output("geojson-mapa", "children"),
    Input("monitoramento-dissolve", "data"),
)
def update_output_mapa(gdf):
    """
    Função para atualização dos dados do mapa.
    """
    # print(json.loads(gdf))
    map_geojson = dl.GeoJSON(
        data=json.loads(gdf),
        zoomToBounds=True,
        zoomToBoundsOnClick=True,
        options={"style":{"color":"red"}},
    )

    return map_geojson

@callback(Output("popup", "children"), [Input("geojson-mapa", "click_feature")])
def capital_click(feature):
    print("passei aqui")
    if feature is not None:
        print("passei aqui")
        return f"You clicked {feature['properties']['name']}"
```

To run all project download it from link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fqmiKH0pKrul9EziTI-Tur_P-TxqOAfP/view?usp=sharing

OBS: The server of dash can be runned from index.py.